# colspan in IE8 and hidden columns

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a table like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:hidden;">0</td>
    <td style="display:hidden;">1</td>
    <td style="display:hidden;">2</td>
    <td>Hi</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">More data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This renders just fine in Chrome and Firefox, but on IE 8 it only renders correctly if I set `colspan="5"`, as if the hidden columns were still being taken into consideration.

How can I work around this, other than adding a `<td style="display:hidden;" colspan="3"></td>` to the second row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're mixing things here.  The table has 5 columns, and CSS only makes some of them show or not, but they are still there. It may show ok in Firefox and Chrome but it's not ok (it may not work in other browsers you haven't checked yet like tablets and what not).
Instead, you could do like `<td><div style='display:none'>1</div></td>`.  In any case, #of columns added should be 5